# How to jump to a tab using VBA code

Tags: dynamics-sl

I'm using VBA code to enter a SiteID on the Purchase Order Maintenance screen while I'm in the Line Items tab.  Unfortunately, it jumps to the shipping information tab when I do this.  What is the vba code to refocus the Line Items tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess no one monitors questions for Dynamics SL.    I figured it out myself:
I Used the ApplSetFocus command to set the focus to a control on the tab I want to switch to.